# How can I tell gpg that I do not want password caching for a specific program?

Tags: gpg, gpg-agent

I'm using `gnupg 2.1.2`. Usually it is quite handy when `gnupg` caches my passwords. But for some sensitive programs I would prefer that `gnupg` does not cache them with `gpg-agent`. I searched a good while on the internet but did not find a lot of useful information. How can I tell `gnupg` that I do not want a passphrase for a specific program cached?

Here is an example. I'm using `Mutt` as my MUA and I encrypt my passwords for all my accounts in a separate file under `~/.mutt/.passwd.gpg`. In my `~/.muttrc` I set

```
source "/usr/bin/gpg -d --quiet  ~/.mutt/.passwd.gpg |"
```

When I start `Mutt` for the first time I will be asked for my private key password by `gpg`. When I have entered it this password will be cached for some time by `gpg`. Hence, when I start `Mutt` again in this interval I am not prompted for my private key password anymore. This means anyone with access to my computer during this time could read my mail or even send mail. How can I tell `gpg` (e.g. by passing an option to `gpg` although the `man`-page does not show any related flag) to prompt for my private key password every time I start `Mutt` (or any other specific program)? I realize it may not even be possible as `gpg` is probably unaware of which program tries to access an encrypted file. But I'd like to have this confirmed by our great community.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your question; as soon as you are using gpg-agent, an attacker taking control of your keyboard can use your GPG credentials... Wouldn't you be better of with gpg-agent uninstalled if this is a concern?

Answer (score 2):

This might not be very elegant, but to me, it works. Just kill the daemon immediately after using `gpg`:

```
killall gpg-agent
```

(yeah, f**k it!)

It will restart automatically next time it is invoked by `gpg` or any other program. And by using it this way, the default time passwords are cached will not change (you may not want the same behavior for other programs).

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for gpg-agent says "gpg-agent uses an environment variable to inform clients about the communication parameters". It doesn't give the actual environment variable name, but some testing indicates that the relevant variable is `GPG_AGENT_INFO`. I would suggest changing your mutt config to the following:

```
source "unset GPG_AGENT_INFO; /usr/bin/gpg -d --quiet  ~/.mutt/.passwd.gpg |"
```

A perhaps simpler solution would be to pass `--no-use-agent` to gpg.

Note that this doesn't prevent an attacker from calling `gpg` with the agent enabled, if your credentials have been cached (perhaps because you let gpg-agent cache them from outside of Mutt). So, even if gpg-agent knew to discriminate against `mutt` specifically, it wouldn't be a very strong security measure.

Comment: Thanks. The Problem is that `gnupg >= 2.1` does neither obey `--no-use-agent` nor `GPG_AGENT_INFO`. At least according to the `man`-page: "GPG_AGENT_INFO This variable was used by GnuPG versions before 2.1"; "--no-use-agent This is dummy option. gpg2 always requires the agent.".

Comment: Ahhh. Right, gpg-agent isn't optional with GnuPG 2.1. Perhaps configuring it with a low value of `--default-cache-ttl` and friends would be good enough? The default appears to be 10 minutes.

Comment: Yeah, I set `default-cache-ttl 0` in `gpg-agent.conf`. However, this will affect all programs.

Comment: `--no-use-agent` is deprecated. no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the agent with 1 second cache interval for example, almost like no cache

`pkill gpg-agent && gpg-agent --default-cache-ttl 1 --use-standard-socket --daemon`